# workflow in XBAP linked with DB via WCF?

Tags: wcf, xbap

now i have wpf hosted (workflow re-hosted designer )in ASP.NET project via .XBAP file ( XAML Brwser APplication ).

I want to integrate my DB with this .XBAP file and that's also via WCF.

i have 2 questions :

1- how do I integrate XBAP with WCF which needs a cs file to work with it? i search alot i knew that is possible but i didnt find the steps.

2- in the beginning i should be in WPF application ( before making the XBAP file ) integrated with DB via somehow like ORM ( Linq ). now I have XBAP which in another project linked with the same DB, but how the file XBAP will understand the costume activities or anything others objects inside it that is the DB is the same or will see it?

I really need help
Thank you